# System.IO.Directory.GetFiles() doesn't list all files

Tags: c#, getfiles

I am using the `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` function to list all executable files from `C:\Windows\System32` with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] files;
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\System32", "*.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

It lists **300** executables:
[image]

But when I list all the files with PowerShell it has **446** executables:
[image]

For example: `C:\Windows\System32\WinSAT.exe`.
It doesn't list this file.
Any idea why it doesn't show me the full list of executable files ?  it misses some files.

Comment: That search you show an image of (Windows Explorer) usually includes sub-folders as well?

Comment: @sellotape oops, yes. I will fix my question.

Comment: @sellotape I updated my question. Check it again.

Comment: It might be a permissions issue. Are you running your program with administrative privileges?

Comment: Get PowerShell to also show you the attributes of the files; that should indicate why they're not returned by `GetFiles()`. Hidden ones should be included, but perhaps System ones are not?

Comment: @sellotape I am not runnign as administrator but after I read your comment I ran Visual Studio as administrator and tried it again and I still get 300 files.

Comment: Please check if the number of executables provieded by your C# program matches the number of the exe files  in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder. Your program might be running in 32-bit x86 mode, even if it is set to AnyCPU, due to Visual Studio hosting it in a 32 bit environment.

Comment: See `Project->Properties->Build` and deselect `Prefer 32-bit` if checked.

Comment: @elgonzo yes, you right. I checked the number of executables in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and it exactly 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are running a 64 bit operating system but try to access this directory running from a C# application compiled to 32 bit. According to [Programming Guide for 64-bit Windows / Running 32-bit Applications / File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector)
:

> The %windir%\System32 directory is reserved for 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. Most DLL file names were not changed when 64-bit versions of the DLLs were created, so 32-bit versions of the DLLs are stored in a different directory. WOW64 hides this difference by using a file system redirector.
>
> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, %windir%\lastgood\system32, or %windir%\regedit.exe, the access is redirected to an architecture-specific path.
>
> ```
> Original Path                Redirected Path for 32-bit x86 Processes Redirected
> %windir%\System32            %windir%\SysWOW64
> %windir%\lastgood\system32   %windir%\lastgood\SysWOW64   
> %windir%\regedit.exe         %windir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe
> ```

So you can either compile your application to x64 or access the missing files via the `%windir%\SysWOW64` folder.

Comment: No need to compile for x64 if the target is AnyCPU. Just go into the project settings, `Build` tab and uncheck `Prefer 32-bit` (assuming x86 execution in the debugger is indeed the reason)

Comment: @elgonzo what if I want it to search in both `system32` and `syswow64` ?

Comment: @E235, i am not sure i understand your question here. If you want to search both in System32 and in SysWOW64, then search in both directories (assuming you adjusted your project settings as i mentioned in my first comment here). Also be aware that if you run your program on a 32-bit Windows version there is no SysWOW64 folder (it only exists in 64-bit Windows versions).

Answer (score -2):

GetFiles will stop when you get an exception.  Exception includes access violations.  Only way of getting all files is to parse directory by directory using recursion.  See code below which writes results to an xml file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WriteFileNamesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. This isn't what is going on at all. If there was an exception raised that would be clear in the asker's program.